# Unable to install typo3 version 6.2.4 on window 8.1

Tags: php, xampp, runtime-error, windows-8.1, typo3-6.2.x

I try to install Typo3 latest version on window 8.1 and i use Xampp control panel(V3.2.1).

I just Create File FIRST_INSTALL on my root folder of project.

even if i un-able to getting installed it. i getting same error "To proceed with the installation, create the file FIRST_INSTALL in your root directory. The filename is case-sensitive but the file itself can be empty."

I try in window 8 o.s. and its works. There is any problem with window 8.1 or any xampp setting will need to do for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did it today on W8.1 with latest Xampp and typo3 source. Have you tried to install typo3 from a subfolder like "project" (xampp\htdocs\project) where all t3 subfolders, the index.php and the blank "FIRST_INSTALL" file were located?